# If $I$ is a right ideal of $fRf$, the right ideal of $R$ generated by $I$ is $I+IR.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily with an identity) and $f \in R$ be an idempotent. Then if $I$ is a
>   right ideal of $fRf$, the right ideal of $R$ generated by $I$ is
>   $I+IR.$

It's easy to see that $I\subseteq I+IR\subseteq \langle I \rangle$, so I tried to prove that $I+IR$ was an ideal of $R$, but I'm having an hard time doing it...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Right on, thanks. Deleting my past comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right ideal of $R$ generated by $I$ must contain $I+IR$. We have only to show that $I+IR$ *is* a right ideal of $R$.

Note that $IR$ is the set of all elements of the form
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x_kr_k
$$
for $x_k\in I$ and $r_k\in R$, where $n$ is any nonnegative integer.

Closure under sum is obvious, as it is the fact that $0\in I+IR$.

An element in $I+IR$ is of the form
$$
x_0+\sum_{k=1}^n x_kr_k
$$
where $x_k\in I$, for $k=0,1,\dots,n$. On the other hand, $x_0=x_0f$, since $x_0\in fRf$. If $s\in R$, then
$$
\biggl(x_0+\sum_{k=1}^n x_kr_k\biggr)=
x_0(fs)+\sum_{k=1}^n x_k(r_ks)\in IR
$$
Actually, this shows the right ideal generated by $I$ is $IR$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why is closure under sums obvious? I don't see why the sum of two elements of $IR$ would necessarily be in $IR. $ Thank you

Comment: @KingGhidorah $IR$ is *not* the set of elements of the form $xr$ with $x\in I$ and $r\in R$, but the set of sums of those elements.

Comment: Of course, silly me. Thanks